# Variable does not exist: Name

Tags: apex, trigger, json, jsongenerator

```
 string objectname;
                                List<sobject> objList;
                                for(Schema.SObjectType reference : fldResult.getReferenceTo()) {
                                string objname=reference.getDescribe().getName();
                                string currentUserId=string.valueOf(campaignOldMap.get(campObj.Id).get(fieldName));
                                objList = (List<sobject>)CM_QueryUtility.queryObjects(
                                            objname, 
                                            new List<String>{'id,Name'},
                                            'id=\''+currentUserId+'\''
                                            ,'',''); 
                                     system.debug('objList'+objList);
                                  }
                                if(objList!=null){
                                    system.debug('objList'+objList);
                                    j2aAttribute.OldValue = objList[0].Name;
                                }
```

Comment: Could be due to your initialization of the list of field names. This is a list, but you have a single string entry in CSV format. Perhaps you should be using "new List<String>{'id','Name'}," instead?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `dot notation` to access field values when accessing values from `sObject`. As `objList` is a `List<sObject>`, you will have to use the [sObject's](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) method to get the value of field

Instead of using

```
objList[0].Name
```

you should be using

```
(String)objList[0].get('Name');
```

**Note :** If you want to use the `dot notation` to access field values, then you will have to typecast the generic `sObject` to a concrete `sObject`.

Comment: Hi @priya if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.